# MSBuild ignores its own ShowTimestamp parameter

Tags: msbuild

The reference for the command line arguments (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) shows that for console and file logger there is a parameter called `ShowTimestamp` which prefixes messages with a timestamp.

How does this work? Reproduction file:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" DefaultTargets="Build">  
    <Target Name="Build">
        <Message Text="Message" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

Call:

```
 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe /clp:ShowTimestamp;ShowEventId dummy.msbuild.xml
```

I can see the `ShowEventId` displayed in the output but the timestamp is missing. I've tried this for /flp as well, no timestamp.
I tried other params like `PerformanceSummary` etc, all fine. I tried setting tool version to `12.0`, same result.

Answer (score 4):

Using reflector I realized that `ShowTimestamp` is used **only** inside `ParallelConsoleLogger` class, so the only way to see timestamp (without writing own logger) is to to force msbuild to use parallel logger, i.e. we need to specify `/m` switch.

Resulting command line for your sample will be

```
msbuild.exe /clp:ShowTimestamp;ShowEventId /m dummy.msbuild.xml
```

If computer has single core (like, virtual build machine), then `/m` will work like `/m:1` and will use simple logger, but you can work around this by specifying `/m:2` for example - it will still use the only available core, BUT it will use `ParallelConsoleLogger`.